# why update option is not working?

Tags: plugin-development

I have following code which is not working:

```
var_dump($resp['status']); //output: 'status' => string 'yes' (length=3) 
update_option('acp_cf_settings' , array('acp_cf_status'=>$resp['status']));
update_option('acp_cf_settings' , array('acp_cf_log'=>$resp['log']));
$options = get_option('acp_cf_settings');
$resp['status'] = $options['acp_cf_status'];
var_dump($resp['status']); //output: 'status' => null
```

Here $resp is an array and 'acp_cf_log' setting is updated but 'acp_cf_status' is not updating, so where I am doing mistake ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update_option('acp_cf_settings' , array('acp_cf_status'=>$resp['status']));
update_option('acp_cf_settings' , array('acp_cf_log'=>$resp['log']));
```

You are overwriting the setting. After the second `update_option` call there is no `acp_cf_status` key anymore for the array variable, just the `acp_cf_log`.

Just to be clear, you would need something like this:

```
update_option( 'acp_cf_settings', array(
    'acp_cf_status' => $resp['status'], 
    'acp_cf_log' => $resp['log'],
) );
```

Comment: yes thats the answer... thank you very much @webtoure